# HTML Text Editor Malfunctioning On Website

Tags: php, html, ckeditor, wysiwyg, text-editor

A blog of mine uses a WYSIWYG Text Editor to add content. For over two months now, I've been using the TinyMCE text editor without any issues. Earlier today, as I went about posting an article on the blog, I noticed a strange issue -

1. Whatever alignment attributes I'd specify via the editor, were being ignored by the Editor as a whole causing it to post all content in center aligned.
2. More importantly, none of the images or links within my article were being displayed.
3. Every time the character **'** or **"** were used, they were preceded by a \

A closer look at this revealed this to be the reason no images were being displayed. Every link specified would be modified automatically on posting as follows -

**Original link**

```
https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xtf1/v/t1.0-9/11986487_415295328664449_5126694793652411223_n.jpg?oh=2e74053db8bc3b2199d83bf70e20bb66&oe=56D18294&__gda__=1456294351_feed673783e94a2b2581dc30cb848aa9
```

**Modified link**

```
\"\\&quot;https:/fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xtf1/v/t1.0-9/11986487_415295328664449_5126694793652411223_n.jpg?oh=2e74053db8bc3b2199d83bf70e20bb66&amp;oe=56D18294&amp;__gda__=1456294351_feed673783e94a2b2581dc30cb848aa9\\&quot;\" alt=\"\"
```

I've tried changing my text editor to that of CKEditor to no avail. The code that is responsible for adding an article seems without a flaw and I'm absolutely confused. It looks like this -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><!-- CDN hosted by Cachefly -->
<a href='login_editor.php'>BACK</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href='index.php'>SITE HOME </a>
<title>Create an Article </title>

<script src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script>tinymce.init({selector:'#content,#summary',
plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"

});</script>

</head>

<body background='hsw.jpg'>


<center>        
<?php
require 'database.php';
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['eid'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])) 

    echo "<script>window.location='login_editor.php'</script>";

$a = $_SESSION['eid'];

      if($_SESSION['eid']==null) 

    echo "<script>window.location='login_editor.php'</script>";

if(isset($_POST['add']))
{

    $email =  $_SESSION['email'];
    $eid=$_SESSION['eid'];
echo $eid;
$title = $_POST['titleofarticle'];
$titleimage=$_POST['titleimage'];
$titleimage = "<img src='".$titleimage."'>";

$summary = $_POST['summary'];
        $article = $_POST['content'];

            $pdo = Database::connect();
echo $eid;
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO editorials (eid,title,titleimage,summary,content) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($eid,$title,$titleimage,$summary,$article));
            Database::disconnect();
            echo "Article Submitted! Reloading this page in 5 sec.<script>setTimeout(function(){
       window.location='login_editor.php';
    }, 5000);</script>";
    }



else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<h3><font face="Small Fonts">Article Title</h3> <br>
        <input  name="titleofarticle" type="text" id="titleofarticle" required size="100"><br><br>
        <h3><font face="Small Fonts">Article Title Image</h3> <br>
        <input name="titleimage" type="text" id="titleimage" placeholder="Image URL" required size="100"> <br><br>
        <h3><font face="Small Fonts">Article Description - Appears Below The Title Image </h3> <br>
        <textarea name="summary" id="summary" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea><br>
        <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'summary' );
            </script>
        <h3><font face="Small Fonts">Article Content</h3> <br>
        <textarea name="content" id="content" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
        <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'content' );
            </script>
    <input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Submit">

</form>


<?php
}
?>
<hr><br>
<a href='logout_editor.php'> LOGOUT </a>
</body>
</html>
```

The same issue occurs even if I try to update an existing article, making older articles that were once perfect even worse. The code that updates an article appears as -

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
    echo "<script>window.location='login_editor.php'</script>";
$id=$_GET['id'];
$eid=$_GET['eid'];

if($_SESSION['eid']!=$eid)
    echo "<script>window.location='login_editor.php'</script>";

  require 'database.php';
 $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM editorials where id = ?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($id));
        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $checkeid = $data['eid'];
        if($_SESSION['eid']!=$checkeid)
            echo "<script>window.location='login_editor.php'</script>";

        Database::disconnect();


?>

<?php





    if ( !empty($_POST)) {

        // keep track post values
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $titleimage_a = $_POST['titleimagelink'];
        $titleimage= "<img src='".$titleimage_a."'>";
        $summary = $_POST['summary'];
        $content = $_POST['content'];


            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "UPDATE editorials  set title = ?,titleimage = ?, summary = ?, content = ? WHERE id = ? AND eid=?";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($title,$titleimage,$summary,$content,$id,$eid));



            Database::disconnect();
            header("Location: login_editor.php");

    }

    else {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM editorials where id = ?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($id));
        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $title = $data['title'];
        $titleimage = $data['titleimage'];
        $titleimagelink_temp=substr($titleimage,10);
        $titleimagelink=substr($titleimagelink_temp,0,-2);
        $summary = $data['summary'];
        $content = $data['content'];

        Database::disconnect();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="1442008266.ico">
<title>Update</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#content,#summary",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
</script>
</head>

<body background='hsw.jpg'>
    <div class="container">

                <div class="span10 offset1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h3>Update Article</h3>
                    </div>

                    <form class="form-horizontal" action="editorupdate.php?id=<?php echo $id?>&eid=<?php echo $eid?>" method="post">
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Title :</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input name="title" type="text" value="<?php echo $title?>" size="100">

                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Title Image:</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input name="titleimagelink" type="text" value="<?php echo $titleimagelink?>" size="100">

                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Summary :</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <textarea name="summary" id="summary"><?php echo $summary?>
                            </textarea>
                            <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'summary' );
            </script>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Content :</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <textarea name="content"  id="content"><?php echo $content?>
                            </textarea>
                            <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'content' );
            </script>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-actions">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                          <a class="btn" href="login_editor.php">Back</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

As a result then, an article which should appear as this -

[image]

Appears as this -

[image]

I've beyond exhausted myself trying to figure out the cause. Reverted to an older backup, scanned my website for malware using a Google tool to no avail. Although my domain host did say they detected malicious code somewhere and suggested I try a $200 tool for malware removal. After I complained a bit, another tech. support representative looked into the issue and had this to say -

[image]

Which didn't seem to relevant. What could possible be the cause of this?

Comment: use `htmlentities()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Thank you for responding Pedro, but could you please be more elaborate as the link doesn't explain enough.

Where should I be inserting the function and why?

Comment: `<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>` should be `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>`.

Comment: @chris85 Just tried pal, doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @jeroen I concur. The code work done by my designer is no way near good enough. Here I am stumped in the middle of the night trying to find a work around.

Security issues aside - you mentioned magic quotes. Is this what's happening here? Seems like it from the link you referred to - is there a way I can overcome this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can change the setting in an `.htaccess` file in the root of your site: `php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off`

Comment: @jeroen THANK YOU. Soon after your last post, I sent time researching on Magic Quotes and quickly found out that my server had the attribute you mentioned ON. I turned them off by accessing the php.ini configuration and voila!

It's annoying because I've been in conversation with the tech team at the domain hosting service all day and all they could suggest was try a $200 package to clean my site of malware - when clearly it was being caused by an attribute on their server. 

Regardless, thank you for your help. I'm now off to get myself a decent developer with some decent money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am surprised this worked at all: It looks as if someone downgraded your server / activated [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php), however:

- You are storing non-validated content in the database and then you output it to html without even using something like [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to make sure you html doesn't break;
- You try to start sessions when you already have outputted content to the browser.

But you biggest problem is that your script is horribly insecure: You are using javascript redirects when you check your session, for example:

```
  if($_SESSION['eid']==null) 
      echo "<script>window.location='login_editor.php'</script>";
```

***This means that your whole script gets executed on the server before the redirect in the browser takes place***.

So anybody could modify and add articles, there is no authentication at all.

You should check for a valid session at the very top of your script and then use a `header` redirect followed with `exit;` to make sure nothing gets executed when no valid user is found.